# selenium findelement vba blocks the routine

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, ms-access, selenium-webdriver

this is my code to open a site and search for objects. It may happen that an object is not found and therefore I have to set up a search on its existence or not, so as to perform or not operations. I'm trying this way but if the object I'm looking for, the routine crashes ....

```
  Dim bot As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  bot.SetProfile "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
  bot.start "chrome", "https://website.com/"
  bot.Open "/"
  bot.wait 10000
  bot.findElementByClassName("_20NlL").Click
  bot.Wait 1000
  bot.findElementByClassName("C28xL").Click
  bot.Wait 1200
  bot.SendKeys text
  bot.Wait 2000
  Dim notext As WebElement
  Set notext = bot.findElementByClassName("_3WZoe", timeoutms:=0)
  If notext Is Nothing Then
  ......[this is the error that is shown to me][1]
```

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWKzW.jpg

what am I wrong?

if I declare bot as webdriver or chromedriver as indicated by QHarr I get this error unfortunately ....

error run-time 33: session not created exception ecc. i'm using chrome 69.0

Comment: Can you share the web url? Or at the very least the page HTML. There can be a number of reasons why you are getting that error.

Comment: @QHarr OP is trying to test if an element with that class exists. I'm not knowledgeable in Selenium but still believe that's the wrong method and will always throw that error if it doesn't exist, so it's MCVE enough for me. I could write up an answer based on error trapping but you'll likely be able to write up a better one

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Hi -  The error says it is unable to locate. If may be unable  locate at this point in time. It may exist somewhere.  Without seeing the html I cannot rule out that it doesn't exist in the html. But I get your point and will remove the MCVE part and simply leave the suggestion we need to see the html to better assist,

Comment: @QHarr But it should be unable to locate it, because it shouldn't exist, as I understand it

Comment: It may exist but be nested inside a frame/iframe/form tag so not be visible at the current document level (common occurrences). With incorrect access path it would generate the above error even if the element in fact does exist on the page.

Comment: Please include the html

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Think light bulb moment may just have come on when I started to look at code properly. I now assume you were referencing the Name part being wrong in className for the access method. Oops.

Comment: first of all thank you all for the answers. I tried to modify the suggested string as well

   Set notext = bot.findElementByClassName("_3WZoe", timeoutms:=500)
but the error is always unfortunately.

The wait are respected correctly.

The same code works perfectly using the seleniumBasic. But I'm trying to switch to the webdriver which is better for managing the chrome profile (it does not require login to the portal again).

The block occurs just when the key I search does not appear. If this appears the routine continues without problems. Am I wrong about this string of code maybe?

Comment: help me please.... :(

Answer (score 2):

A number of the errors I can see make me think you have translated this across from another language, or are working with syntax not designed for current [selenium basic wrapper](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic).

1) For selenium basic the following `timeoutms` is not a named argument. The correct named argument is `timeout` so something is odd with your reported error as you should have received a named argument error message.

2) Simply declare as `Dim bot As New WebDriver` or `New ChromeDriver` if using Chrome.

3) The correct method with selenium basic is `FindElementByClass`

---

Your `sendKeys` likely should be focused on a specific element e.g.

```
bot.findElementByClass("C28xL").SendKeys Text
```

---

You can check whether an element is currently present with

```
bot.findElementByClass("_3WZoe", timeout:=0, Raise:=False)
```

Again, bearing in mind the point around navigating parent `form/frame/iframe` tags and wait times.

---

Ensure you are using the latest Chrome browser and [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/). The ChromeDriver should be on the [environmental path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v%3Doffice.14)) i.e. in a folder which is on the enviromental path and that the path section (for the driver) should be up to, but not including, the .exe (i.e. to the containing folder level). You can alternatively specify the location to look in for the driver as a statement within the code.

Comment: With seleniumbasic I use just the string as you wrote
        bot.findElementByClassName("_3WZoe", timeout:=0, Raise:=False)
 it and it works. 
The problem is with webdriver.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
Set notext = bot.findElementByClassName("_3WZoe", timeoutms:=0)
```

Your are *explicitly* setting `timeoutms:=0`. You're giving it no time to try to find the element on the page. Take that parameter out of your call, give it time to find the element on the page. It's going to run on the default timeout value (don't recall what it is off the top of my head), but should return quickly in most cases. You've already waited 2 seconds from your previous `sendKeys` command, so it's *likely* (though not guaranteed) that the element will have loaded by then.

---

Additionally, it's entirely possible that the element you're looking for resides in a frame somewhere on the page and that you'll have to switch to the proper frame before you ever have a chance of `findElementBy<anyoftheoptions>` ever working.

That was one of the biggest issues I had was just the lack of understanding enough HTML to get through the web page source quickly and easily enough to make "light work" of the project. I did, with enough trial and error, eventually get there though.

---

Also, I'd strongly recommend that you wrap the whole thing in some error handling to be able to catch and gracefully recover from errors. You're dealing with web servers and the internet and general traffic outside the realm of your LAN - there *will be* timeouts. It would be good for your code to not blow up for things that are well beyond your control.

Comment: yeah and that! +1 And isn't it just timeout:=  ? Those if it didn't complain then I guess it is an additional argument parameter.

Comment: @QHarr based on his error, I think he's got the parameter name correct, but I haven't opened my project to look at my Selenium code and just don't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Agreed. I would have expected a different error had that been the case. Just _pleasantly_ surprised to see a different timeout. If that is milliseconds, for example, then consideration needs to go for that in terms of the value set.