# Click related to doPostBack & href in VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I was having trouble with coding and I could no longer work.

https://tradingeconomics.com/

I posted the coding logic I was working on below. I imported the excel sheet to Portugal of the countries shown on the homepage.

But,

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_LinkButton1" class="btn-group btn-group-sm" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$LinkButton1','')">
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">
      <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </ i>
   </ button>
</a>
```

How can I code doPostBack to finish my work here? I looked through stackoverflow homepage and tried various trial and error, but I could not finish it.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub New_Listing()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sResponse0 As String
Dim g As Integer

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim url As String

url = "https://tradingeconomics.com/"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://tradingeconomics.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With

Dim tarTable As HTMLTable
Dim hTable As HTMLTable

For Each tarTable In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    If InStr(tarTable.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_GridView1") <> 0 Then
    Set hTable = tarTable
    End If
Next

    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long

    r = startRow
    With ws
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        ReDim arr0(tRow.Length - 1, 0)
        For Each tr In tRow
            r = r + 1
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")

            If tCell.Length > UBound(arr0, 2) Then
            ReDim Preserve arr0(tRow.Length - 1, tCell.Length)
            End If

            c = 1
            For Each td In tCell
                arr0(r - 1, c - 1) = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td

        Next tr

        Dim k As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        k = 0
        For i = LBound(arr0, 1) To UBound(arr0, 1)
            .Cells(2 + k, 2) = arr0(i, 0)
            .Cells(2 + k, 3) = arr0(i, 1)
            .Cells(2 + k, 4) = arr0(i, 2)
            .Cells(2 + k, 5) = arr0(i, 3)
            .Cells(2 + k, 6) = arr0(i, 4)
            .Cells(2 + k, 7) = arr0(i, 5)
            .Cells(2 + k, 8) = arr0(i, 6)
            .Cells(2 + k, 9) = arr0(i, 7)
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    End With

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .document.querySelector("a.btn-group btn-group-sm[href='javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$LinkButton1','')']").Click
    End With

Set tRow = Nothing: Set tCell = Nothing: Set tr = Nothing: Set td = Nothing
Set hTable = Nothing: Set tarTable = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have completed my work up to Portugal, how can I fix it to get the next data, Czech Republic ?, I would be very grateful if you could give me details of how to modify the coding. I have learned vba very soon, so I have a lot of difficulties.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viCwV.jpg)

Comment: Are you open to using selenium basic as well?

Comment: Thanks to QHarr, I am learning a lot from QHarr's articles on this homepage. I have not used selenium basic yet, but I downloaded the selenium basic material to my computer. I am going to use it if I can afford to live, but now I can not afford to live. selenium basic If you study a little, you will be able to handle your work more easily, but I have a lot of things to do in the past, so I can not afford to. First of all, I will give priority to finishing things from what I already study.

Comment: I have given  an internet explorer answer which does all the data in one go including the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Internet Explorer**

Here with IE - get's all results  (the whole World) in one go including links.

Condition based wait with timeout:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, clipboard As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Const URL = "https://tradingeconomics.com/"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[value=world]").Selected = True
            .querySelector("select").FireEvent "onchange"
            t = Timer
            Do
            DoEvents
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_ParameterContinent").Value <> "world"

            clipboard.SetText .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_GridView1").outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
        End With
        .Quit
        ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

Explicit wait based:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, clipboard As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Const URL = "https://tradingeconomics.com/"
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[value=world]").Selected = True
            .querySelector("select").FireEvent "onchange"

             Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

             clipboard.SetText .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_GridView1").outerHTML
             clipboard.PutInClipboard
        End With
        .Quit
        ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Selenium basic**

This is easy enough using [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) and allowing enough time for the postBack to update the page. After selenium basic install add reference via VBE> Tools > References > Selenium Type Library. More selenium info [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185212/6241235). The below gets all the World data in one go.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, ws As Worksheet, clipboard As Object
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Const URL = "https://tradingeconomics.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementByCss("[value=world]").Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

        clipboard.SetText .FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_GridView1").Attribute("outerHTML")
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        .Quit
        ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow ... your coding output is amazing. IE coding is really good. And then .. I just installed the Selenium basic on my computer and tried to use your coding results. I checked the Selenium Type Library, but I get an error.

33 runtime err.
SessionNotCreatedError
session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid
'context':
{"auxData": {frameid ":" 21828B311DAD0D41D57FF8B55301D1CA
, "isDefau

(Session info: chrome = 70.0.3538.102)

Comment: Not sure but start by checking through the list of requirements and issues in the second link in my selenium answer; where it says _here_.  If after that still a problem let me know and I will see what we can do.

Answer (score 2):

The `Czech Republic` value is part of a values set which is returned from the server after clicking a button in the web page itself, you'll have to simulate a click on this button by the VBA code, wait for IE to fetch the result and then continue with your code:

As this is the HTML of the button for fetching the next set of values:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">...
```

Use this to simulate a click and wait for the result fetched:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-default")(0).Click
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

After it you will be able to read the `Czech Republic` and the next set of values by the VBA code.